# node's coordinates in javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a question.. well, I use this code to get my node's coordinates

```
Bounds localToScreen = myNode.localToScene(myNode.getBoundsInLocal());
localToScreen.getMinX();
localToScreen.getMinY();
localToScreen.getWidth();
localToScreen.getHeight();
```

but this code just sometimes works and In the other times it shows wrong results.. so is there any thing special about using this code? why doesn't it work any times? In scenebuilder all the node's coordinates are right.

this is an example

my fxml file is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <?import java.lang.*?>
   <?import java.util.*?>
   <?import javafx.scene.*?>
   <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
   <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


   <AnchorPane fx:id="anchor" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity"        minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"   xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="test.FXMLDocumentController">
     <children>
      <HBox fx:id="hbox" layoutX="147.0" layoutY="67.0" prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <TextField />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

and my controller is 
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

```
@FXML
private AnchorPane anchor;
@FXML
private HBox hbox;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    Bounds localToScreen = hbox.localToScene(hbox.getBoundsInLocal());
    System.out.print(""+
    localToScreen.getMinX() +"  "+
    localToScreen.getMinY() +"  "+
    localToScreen.getWidth()+"   "+
    localToScreen.getHeight()
    );
    // TODO
}
```

the result is

```
147.0  67.0  0.0   0.0
```

width and height should not be 0!

please help.. thanks

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates this showing the "wrong results". As long as the node is present in the scene graph, and the scene graph has been laid out, you should get the correct results. Also, can you clarify if you are looking for the coordinates in the *scene* (which is what you are getting) or the coordinates on the *screen* (which is what you called the variable)?

Comment: I edited my question and add a sample code to it.

Comment: Assuming that is the `initialize()` method if a controller class, then the `hbox` cannot possibly have been added to a scene when that code is executed. So getting the coordinates relative to the scene cannot possibly give you anything meaningful. You need to execute that code after the node has been placed in a scene and the scene has undergone layout.

Comment: I also have this problem when I write my code in the application class.. so you mean when I get this parameters  , the related node might not have been added to the scene, so I get the wrong result?

Comment: oh, thank you @James_D I write it after showing the stage and it works!